# Getting information from non visible pages

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Requirements:Go to indeed.com
In what field use QA Engineer and  in where field use Seattle, WA.
Print job description/title from all the pages excluding Amazon or Automation

Problem: In Firepath this xpath I am using //div[contains(@id,'p')][contains(@class,'row')]  selects all the
jobs in the 1st page. However when I execute the code below it just prints the very 1st job description of the 1st page
over and over again, while keeps on clicking on the other pages simultaneously.

Output I am getting:

SENIOR QUALITY ASSURANCE ENGINEER- CIVIL...
Sound Transit - 12 reviews - Seattle, WA
$79,626 - $99,533 a year
Mentors, coaches and guides QA Engineers in maintaining the established standards of work. Supports consistency within the QA group by providing guidance to QA...
save job
Sponsored

Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


public class QAJob {
    int MAX_PAGES;

    @Test
    public void jobSearch(){
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.indeed.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("what")).sendKeys("QA Engineer");
        driver.findElement(By.id("where")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("where")).sendKeys("Seattle,WA");
        driver.findElement(By.id("fj")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Close the pop up window that appears
        driver.findElement(By.id("prime-popover-close-button")).click();

        //Code to scroll down
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "");

        //Find and print the number of pages found for search       
        List<WebElement> search_pages=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pagination')]//a"));
        System.out.println("Number of pages found for job search is " +search_pages.size());

        //Code to get and print job descriptions,title  
        List<WebElement> job_desc=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'p')][contains(@class,'row')]"));

        for(WebElement e: job_desc){
            //using String so that I can use 'contains'
            String str_job_description=e.getText();

                while(search_pages.size()!=0){

                    //find Next link and click on it till the size is !=0 to get to last page
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'np')][contains(text(),'Next')]")).click(); 
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    //Do not want Amazon or Automation jobs
                    if(!((str_job_description.contains("Automation")) || (str_job_description.contains("Amazon"))) ){
                        System.out.println(str_job_description);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I could use some helpful suggestion/ideas. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each element you have in `job_desc` (outer `for` loop) you are clicking on next button until you reach the last page (inner `while` loop). The `for` loop should be inside the `while`. You can try something like this (not tested)

```
while(search_pages.size() != 0) {
    List<WebElement> job_desc=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'p')][contains(@class,'row')]"));
    for(WebElement e: job_desc){
        String str_job_description=e.getText();
        if(!((str_job_description.contains("Automation")) || (str_job_description.contains("Amazon"))) ){
            System.out.println(str_job_description);
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'np')][contains(text(),'Next')]")).click(); 
}
```

As a side note, no need to define implicit wait `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait` each iteration, define it once when you create the `driver`. If you want to wait there use explicit wait with [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By by));
```